# How to validate my email address with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Just started out with `regex` and struggling to find the right expression. It should contain one "@" character and before and after the "@" it should contain at least one and at most 64 chars which are letters/numbers or dots.

```
valid: mark@mail.com 
valid: .@. 
invalid: @example.com
```

I tried: `([a-zA-Z]+\d+\b.@.\b[a-zA-Z]+\d+)`
don't get how you mark a character optional. What `regex` would work?

Update: I tried that suggestion ie other solution , did not work for me : (

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: @alfasin not working for me unfortunately

Comment: "not working for me" is not helpful. Post what did you try, which input you ran on, what was the result vs. what is the expected result. You have enough rep to know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below regex to match email id.

```js
var emailValidation = function(str){
  return /^[a-zA-Z\d\.]{1,64}@[a-zA-Z\.\d]{1,64}$/.test(str);
}

console.log(emailValidation('mark@mail.com'));
console.log(emailValidation('.@.'));
console.log(emailValidation('@example.com'));
```

Comment: Instead of `match` use `RegExp#test`.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar. Updated the solution.